# Сайт на мобильных не должен уменьшаться

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, так сложилось, что заказчик пожелал вместо обычной мобильной версии сайта, что бы сайт всегда отражался как через комп, т.е. не зависимо с какого устройства вы зашли сайт должен быть всегда шириной 1000px и не важно, помещается он во весь экран или нет но ширина должна быть 1000. [Сам сайт](http://tarasik22.tmweb.ru/)

Comment: Попрпобуйте удалить `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: По мне так задать общему контейнеру фиксированный размер 1000px и всё. или я не так понял вопроса

Comment: Я пробывал и width 1000 и max width 1000 min width 1000 и всё равно при просмотре с  планшета меню не всё видно-съезжает

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Пробывал, не помогает